# TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str 4

Tags: python, string, int

I'm trying to make a code that simply puts an "o" in front of every consonant in any word given and I don't know where to go from here, I just get the error `"TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str"`

```
k = list('b' + 'c' + 'd' + 'f' + 'g' + 'h' + 'j' + 'k' + 'l' + 'm' + 'n' + 'p' + 'q' + 'r' + 's' + 't' + 'v' + 'w' + 'x' + 'z')
for bok in k:
    text = list(raw_input("Give a phrase to code: "))
    print bok["0"]
```

Comment: You can iterate over strings character by characters; `k='bcd...z'` is sufficient (for the same reason, `k=list('bcd...z')` works if you really want a list of 25 one-character strings).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easier approach would be to use a regular expression, eg:

```
import re

print re.sub('([bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz])', r'o\1', 'tobias')
# otoobiaos
```

This looks for any of the inbetween the `[]` (the consonants) and replaces it with `o` followed by the letter it found.

Eg, getting user input:

```
word = raw_input('Enter a word: ')
print re.sub('([bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz])', r'o\1', word)
```

Comment: That certainly solves my problem! But if I want the user to be able to write any word he/she wants so the word comes out with an "o" in front of every consonant like "otoobiaos", how do I do that? I know I have to use raw_input at least.

Comment: @Tobias yup - prompt using something like `word = raw_input('Enter word: ')` and pass `word` instead of the literal `'tobias'` into the function

Comment: Just another question, if I want the "o" to appear after the consonant how do I do that? Do I still use the same function?

Comment: @Tobias yes... the `\1` represents the found character... the `o` is just a literal... I've leave it to you to put the rest together :)

Answer (score 2):

You are using `print bok["0"]`, using the string "0" as the index. You need to use an integer, so replace like so:

```
  print bok[0]
```

I'm not sure I understand your overall goal here, but this will resolve the error for which you posted this question.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, array indexing is done with integers, not strings:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> a["0"]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
>>> a[0]
1
```

Secondly, you can make a string without using so many `+`es:

```
>>> 'b' + 'c' + 'd'
'bcd'
>>> 'bcd'
'bcd'
```

Thirdly, you can iterate through a string without having to turn it into a list:

```
>>> for c in list("abc"):
...     print c
... 
a
b    
c
>>> for c in "abc":
...     print c
... 
a
b        
c
```

Fourthly, iterating through a string gives you a string with each character in turn. You don't have to get the 0th index of that string - that's the same thing:

```
>>> "b"
'b'
>>> "b"[0]
'b'
>>> "b"[0] == "b"
True
```